# Python Binary Search Tree Delete Function

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BST:
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root


    def remove(self, val):

        if self.root == None:
            return root
        else:
            self._remove(val, self.root)

    def _remove(self, val, node):
        if node == None:
            return node # Item not found

        if val < node.val:
            self._remove(val, node.left)
        elif val > node.val:
            self._remove(val, node.right)
        else: 
            # FOUND NODE TO REMOVE
            if node.left != None and node.right != None: # IF TWO CHILDREN
                node.val = self._find_min(node.right)
                node.right = self._remove(node.val, node.right)
            else: # ZERO OR ONE CHILD
                if node.left == None: # COVERS ZERO CHILD CASE 
                    node = node.right
                elif node.right == None:
                    node = node.left      

        return node
```

Cannot figure out why this function will not delete some values. I debugged with print statements and can see that if I try to remove a value, the function will enter the else block and successfully remove a node with two children. However, when attempting to remove a node with one or zero children, the codes executes with no errors, but when I print the tree to view its contents the node is still there.

The node to be removed will have at least one None child, and it seems straightforward to set the node equal to its right (or left) child, which I assume sets the node to None.

I have some experience with Java, but fairly new to Python, and I sometimes run into trouble with the "self" protocol, but I don't think that is the case here.

Comment: The problem is that `node = node.right` doesn't modify anything. All it does is rebind the local variable`node` to be a name for what used to be `node.right` instead of a name for the original `node`. You need to either pass the parent node down the recursive chain so it can be modified, or pass the change information up the chain and modify things on the way up. (The latter is probably more complicated to reason about and to implement, but it might be worth considering if you're going to add self-balancing later.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement what you suggested - passing the parent node down the recursive chain. Aren't I at the end of the line when I reach the parent node? I was getting a NoneType error when I tried to pass the parent node recursively through _remove() because the node was equal to None

Comment: No, the _parent_ is the one closer to the top; the _child_ is the one below it. So, at each recursive call, instead of passing `node.right`, you'd also pass `node` (and a flag telling it whether it's the left or right that's being changed). Then you'd actually have something you can actually modify. But, while we're at it, the way you've designed things, you already _need_ to return something up the chain. After all, you're doing `node.right = self._remove(node.val, node.right)`, but you never return anything, so this always sets `node.right` to `None`, chopping off the whole right subtree.

Comment: In other words, your implementation is sort of halfway between push-down and push-up, and not doing either one of them right. I can't really explain how to fix it without completely rewriting it—and if you want that, you can just find any of the million example implementations online and copy that.